# How to interpret the R2 in univariate regression analysis?

Tags: regression

How to interpret the R2 in univariate regression analysis ?

Comment: You should expand the question to improve its usefulness to readers.

Comment: This question has been asked and answered on numerous posts on this site.

Comment: I think you will find the information you need in the linked thread. Please 
read it. If it isn't what you want / you still have a question afterwards, 
come back here & edit your question to state what you learned & what you still 
need to know. Then we can provide the information you need without just 
duplicating material elsewhere that already didn't help you.

Comment: I want to understand you my question  by giving  example...suppose my lab value is my dependent variable and age is independent variable, and I got the R2 value 0.028 and  P value 0.012.Now i don't understand how to interpret this R2 value?    second thing I have the idea about the R2 value indicates how much of the dependent variable can be explained by the independent variable. Can you please brief me the interpretation....